# For a mutual fund, where can I find the AUM?

Tags: mutual-funds

Given a mutual fund, where can I find its AUM (assets under management)?

I am seeing a number on its page called "Total asset value". Is that the AUM? I don't think it is, because the number seems too low, and if its AUM, why wouldn't they call it AUM?

I also looked at the balance sheet of the fund, and looked up the value of assets, but that is wrong too.

What is AUM even? I thought it was the total value of the portfolio. After all, that's the assets you are managing, no? The internet definition says its what people have "invested into the fund", but I don't understand why the two should be different? The portfolio is made up of those investments, so the value of the portfolio = assets under management. Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Assets under management (AUM) is the total market value of the securities and cash that a fund contains.  AUM fluctuates daily because of share price change as well as investor deposits and withdrawals to/from the fund.

Fund managers such as Fidelity, Vanguard, etc. provide various stats for each of their funds.  They will include the total net assets, asset allocation (country and sector) and typically, the top ten holdings of the fund.  These are usually end of month stats, often provided a month or so later.

Comment: What are `total net assets` net of?

Comment: Vanguard and T. Rowe Price use "Total Net Assets".  Fidelity uses "Portfolio Net Assets", Schwab uses "Total Assets".  Do the different descriptions confuse you?